# How to explicitly set ProcessAffectedObjects to false when using CaptureXml on AMO Server object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, etl, amo

I'm currently generating XMLA scripts to process various parts of our data warehouse. I've found one situation where doing incremental updates I would prefer having ProcessAffectedObjects = false, but I'm having a hard time finding where to set that in the docs.

The basic code I'm using is as follows:

```
conn.CurrentServer.CaptureXml = true;
dimensions.ForEach(x => x.Process(ProcessType.ProcessUpdate));
conn.CurrentServer.CaptureXml = false;
conn.CurrentServer.ConcatenateCaptureLog(true,true,true).Dump();
server.ExecuteCaptureLog(true, true, true);
```

I've been digging through various overloads of [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149075.aspx#M:Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ProcessableMajorObject.Process(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ProcessType,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ErrorConfiguration,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaWarningCollection,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ImpactDetailCollection,System.Boolean)), thinking perhaps that 5th parameter of `bool analyzeImpactOnly` would set it, but it doesn't seem to generate the appropriate XMLA. I would prefer not to edit the XMLA directly, but I will if I have to. For reference, the `conn.CurrentServer` object is an instance of [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.server.aspx).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annnnd I found the answer two seconds after posting.

When you execute the XMLA generated, the third parameter is `bool processAffected`.

server.ExecuteCaptureLog(true, true, **false**);

**Edit:** Apparently this doesn't work either. The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149330.aspx#M:Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.ConcatenateCaptureLog(System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean)) say that the parameter is "reserved for future use."

Looks like I'll be modifying the XMLA directly.